# Return value of indexOf in Java Exercise

Tags: java, arraylist, indexof

So I got this small fragment of code:

My application is creating an `ArrayList<>` and adding two Strings to it.

```
import java.util.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

    a.add(0, "zero");
    a.add(1, "one");

    if (a.indexOf("two") != 1) {
        a.add(2, "two");
    }
}
```

And there is an `if` statement.

So, I read on API doc that `indexOf` returns the index of the specified element (in this case "two"), but if this element isn't in the list it will return `-1`. `!= 1` means that this return value `-1` is different than `4` so the statement is true and the instructions in the if block will be executed (add a String with the index `2` to the list).

Did I get it right?

Thanks Anyway.

Comment: You are correct, better code would be using the `contains` method first: `if (a.contains("two") && a.indexOf("two") != 1)`

Comment: Are you trying to check if an element is at a specific position, or if it exists at all?

Comment: @RoelStrolenberg Better code would prefer O(2n) instead of O(n)? Nice to know. And do you know, that `contains` is implemented as `indexOf(o) >= 0;`? So you're calling `indexOf` two times ...

Comment: Rather than `a.indexOf("two") != 1`, don't you mean `a.indexOf("two") != -1`? It won't be `1` either, because `a.get(1)` would be `"one"`. But that's probably not what you meant, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you got it right.
But, out of curiosity why are you not using:

```
if (!a.contains("two")) {
    a.add(2, "two");
}
```

Also,
Why are you not simply adding the strings without explicitly providing the index?
Its an ArrayList, the values will be always ordered.

```
    a.add("zero");
    a.add("one");

    if (a.indexOf("two") !=1) {
      a.add("two");
    }
```

If you explicitly provide index but also insert conditionally, your code can easily go wrong.